# IOS/objective-c/core-data: How to get attribute from related entity

Tags: ios, objective-c, core-data, relationship

I have a detail view where I display attributes of an object from an entity in core data.

The entity has a one-to-one relationship with another entity that has other data.  Because I don't understand relationships that well, it may not be set up correctly.

How can I display data from the other entity?

In .h file, I have:

```
 @property (nonatomic, strong) Persons *person;
    @property (nonatomic, strong) Addresses *address;
    @property (strong, nonatomic) NSManagedObjectContext *managedObjectContext;
```

In .m file in viewDidLoad I have:

```
 self.nameLabel.text = self.person.name;//displays fine
 self.addressLabel.text = self.address.address//does not display
NSLog(@"address:%@",self.address.address);//displays (null)
```

Thanks for any suggestions.

Answer (score 0):

Considering you have saved person object in the view controller, then just follow the relationship by person.address to get other entities.

Comment: can you elaborate?  self.person.address throws error (no address found in person)

Comment: Please describe your model then, put your sample project to github is even better. I have misunderstood the issue obviously.